# Python - Removing strings that follow a wildcard pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing, wildcard

Initial Data (String datatype)

```
Los Gatos 50K
Las Palmas Canary Islands 25K
Roland Garros
Seoul 25K
Rome
```

Desired Result

```
Los Gatos
Las Palmas Canary Islands
Roland Garros
Seoul
Rome
```

I am looking for a way to remove any string pattern that is 2 digits and then a K. But it needs to be able to handle any 2 values before the K. I haven't seen any answers that use a wildcard for the part of the replace. It should be something like this (I know this is not valid) -
`data.replace("**K", '')`

Side note - This string will be a column in a dataframe so if there is an easy solution that works with that would be ideal. If not I can iterate through each row and transform it that way.

Comment: try this regex `\d\dK`

Comment: I don't think you want `'\d{2}K'` since it will also remove `10K` in `2010KB`. I believe you need `r'\b\d{2}K\b'`. And to remove any whitespaces before, you should use `df.replace(r'\s*\b\d{2}K\b', '', regex = True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
df = df.replace('\d{2}K', '', regex = True)


    0
0   Los Gatos
1   Las Palmas Canary Islands
2   Roland Garros
3   Seoul
4   Rome
```

Comment: @bbennett36, thats great. All the best